# Receiving "'dict' object is not callable" error while trying to write to Excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, json, dictionary, openpyxl

I am trying to copy a dictionary pulled from an API GET request to excel using openpyxl; however, the code is generating "'dict' object not callable" error. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from openpyxl import Workbook

r = requests.get('API URL & apikey')
data = r.json()
pprint(data)
```

At this point the data comes back in a subnested library form, e.g.:

```
{'results': [{'A':'alpha','B':'beta','C':'gamma'},
             {'D':'delta','E':'epsilon','F':'zeta'}
             ...
             {dictionary n}]
```

Because each GET request from the API results in an unknown number of nested library objects, I wrote code to separate and rename each sub-library into it's own variable:

```
for n, val in enumerate(data['results']):
   globals()["year%d"%n] = val
```

This results in a number of libraries, each assigned to their own variable. All are <class 'dict'>. I test this by running:

```
all_variables = dir()
for name in all_variables:
   if not name.startswith('__'):
       myvalue = eval(name)
       print(name, "is", type(myvalue), "and is equal to:")
       print(myvalue)
       print(" ")
```

Which results in:

```
year1 is <class 'dict'> and is equal to:
   {'A':'alpha','B','beta','C','gamma'}

year2 is <class 'dict'> and is equal to:
   {'D':'delta','E','epsilon','F':'zeta'}

...

yearN is...
```

This is where the problem occurs. When I try to write one of these new dictionaries to Excel using openpyxl, I get the error:

```
32. workbook = Workbook()
33. sheet = workbook.active
34. for key,values in year1():
35.     next_row = 1
36.     sheet.cell(column=1 , row=next_row, value=key)
37.     sheet.cell(column=2 , row=next_row, value=values)
38.     next_row += 1
39.
40. document_name = "yr1"
41. fullfilename = os.path.join(r'filelocation',document_name+'.xlsx')
42. workbook.save(fullfilename)
```

The resulting error is as follows:

```
line 34, in <module> for key,values in year1():
   TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean `year1.items()` in line 34?

```py
for key,values in year1.items():
    next_row = 1
    sheet.cell(column=1 , row=next_row, value=key)
    sheet.cell(column=2 , row=next_row, value=values)
    next_row += 1
```

From the python documentation on [looping techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques):

> When looping through dictionaries, the key and corresponding value can be retrieved at the same time using the items() method.
>
> ```py
> >>> knights = {'gallahad': 'the pure', 'robin': 'the brave'}
> >>> for k, v in knights.items():
> ...    print(k, v)
> ...
> gallahad the pure
> robin the brave
> ```

Comment: Wow, so simple - can't believe I missed it. year1.items() worked perfectly. Thank you @willcrack